# setting a div equivalent to Cartesian coordinates with (origin at left bottom

Tags: jquery, mousemove

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/T6nn5/26/) is my code

Here x,y coordinates start from the left top corner of "working-area" . but I want to set x, y coordinate at left bottom corner of that div.

please anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/T6nn5/28/) you go.

```
    var y = $(this).height() - (e.pageY - pos.top + 1);
```

The problem is that your `#working_area` and the `GRID` my be of same dimension with same alignment. But it seems that where you have implemented, the grid does not seem to fit, Therefore it would be best to give the `working area` the exact size of the grid.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but at some point it return 0. and then -ve value.

Comment: @Moumita can you tell me on which side does it do so?

Comment: you can check on [mysite](http://ushatech.com/customer/Palletized_Material_Handling_Conveyors/build.php?num1=50&num2=50).

Comment: @Moumita you are still sticking to that ... js grid of yours, honestly i would have switched for Java Applet or flash. However check update in 10 min.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to your code shoudl do the trick

```
    var height = $(this).height();
    var z = (pos.top + height) - e.pageY;
```

What it does is calculate the bottom based on th top plus the height, then subtract the position from that.

Comment: at some point it return 0. and then -ve value. I want after 0 mouse move point will not show.